# Benefeciary ： 受益者 vs 获得者

Tags: usage, vocabulary

What is the accurate word for Beneficiary (Eg. A beneficiary of a bank account) in Mandarin Chinese ? What is the difference in usage of 受益者 and 获得者 ?

Comment: 受益人 is used for insurance.

Comment: You maybe have to edit the question, 受益者 not 受益着

Comment: Edited.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beneficiary is translated as 受益人 and 获益者 in Google Translate

> In life insurance lingo, '**受益人**' is the standard legal term for '**the beneficiary**'. When the 受保人 (the insured) dies, the 保險賠償 (insurance claim) goes to the  受益人 (beneficiary)

~

> 受益者, 获益者, 获利者  all mean "**people who are benefited**" in general sense
>
> Example: '美國今次減稅的受益者衹有大企業及億萬富豪' (the only beneficiaries to the US tax cuts this time are the big companies and billionaires)
>
> *you can replace 受益者 with 获益者 or 获利者 in this sentence*

~

> 获得者 literally means "the one who obtain or receive.

Example:'奖金获得者' 或 '奖牌获得者' 都可以简称为 '获奖者' ('people who received a cash prize' or 'people who received a medal' can both be simply called 'winner' )